# My PHP/JS contact form is not doing anything when I click send

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

I have created a simple portfolio website through Github pages, but I cannot get the contact form to work. You can see the [contact form here](https://olivier-watches.com/contacts.html).

When I click on send, nothing ever happens, and I cannot figure out why the code is not connected, as everything seems like it was in the template at the beginning.

Here is the JS code:

```
    $("#contactform").submit(function () {
        var a = $(this).attr("action");
        $("#message").slideUp(750, function () {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $.post(a, {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                comments: $("#comments").val()
            }, function (a) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = a;
                $("#message").slideDown("slow");
                $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                if (null != a.match("success")) $("#contactform").slideDown("slow");
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#contactform input, #contactform textarea").keyup(function () {
        $("#message").slideUp(1500);
    });
    $(".mob_filter-btn").on("click", function () {
        $(".inline-filters-wrap .gallery-filters").fadeToggle(400);

    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
                        <div id="contact-form" class="fl-wrap">
                            <div id="message"></div>
                            <form  class="custom-form" action="php/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name *" value="">
                                    <input type="text"  name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email *" value="">
                                    <textarea name="comments"  id="comments" cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Your message:"></textarea>
                                    <button class="btn float-btn flat-btn color-bg" id="submit" type="submit">Send </button>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];


if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have entered an invalid e-mail address. Please try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = "myemailchanged@gmail.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "E-mail: $email\r\nPhone: $phone";
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;


$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h3>Email sent successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>. Your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction as I don't even know where to look? I have tried searching the web but couldn't find explanations on how the code works. I figured (at least broadly) what each piece of the code does, but cannot understand where the problem lies. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your HTML form does not have a submit button. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-typebutton-and-input-typesubmit/

Comment: add `type=submit` to the button please

Comment: Since the button isn't inside the form, it won't trigger the form's submit event. When it does, you'll need to prevent the default postback behaviour - check out jquery's preventDefault function. Or you could just handle the "click" event of the button instead directly, and forget about the form.

Comment: I have tried adding type=submit to the button, but it still doesn't work. Does it need to be <input type=submit kind of button in order for it to work?

Comment: Who has told you to put </form> right after <form ...> ???? Move `</form>` AFTER `<button type=submit....>`  please

Comment: Like I said, the submit button would need to be _inside_ the form for it to trigger the form submit action. Or you must add the right attribute to the button to link it to the form (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#form)

Comment: I suggest you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form because you seem to have skipped learning the basics of html forms

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how this happened, but the tags were all right in my code. I have edited the HTML syntax above now, and the button is inside the </form> closing tag. Can I add onClick on the button to make it work?

Comment: If you've put the button inside the form it should submit fine. But then use preventDefault as I said before otherwise it'll post back instead of using ajax. Again you can surely find examples online already of how to submit a form using jQuery ajax

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm missing even the basics, but where should I add the event.preventDefault(); method? I am also having trouble figuring out how preventing the action will actually make it go through, it's just so confusing..

Comment: None of this is new stuff, there are zillions of tutorials and examples already that you can follow in order to know what to do. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: `how preventing the action will actually make it go through`...it stops the _normal_ postback behaviour of a HTML form (which you'd know about if you'd done some basic tutorials about HTML forms and PHP) where it refreshes the page completely. You have to stop that happening if you want the JS and AJAX code to run instead.

Comment: Another problem you're going to have later on is with `$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;`. Spoofing someone else's email address when sending email from your own server is a great way to get your emails marked as spam, or blocked completely. I don't think you'd like it if I was using my PHP code to send emails which pretended to be from you?? So don't do that. Instead set the "from" field as a fixed address on the same domain as your mailserver (e.g. "noreply@yourdomain.com") and include the email address from the submitted form somewhere in the email body, and/or the reply-to header

Comment: I'd also strongly encourage you to use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send email instead of the old mail() function. It's much more robust because you don't have to build all the mail headers etc manually, and it has better error handling and debugging info available etc. Sending email correctly can be tricky, so using a library where someone has solved a lot of the problems for you already is a very sensible idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. For the email issue, I have added an email here so it shows after the name, in the body:

$e_body = "You have been contacted by: $name from $email" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

and changed this syntax to remove the user emails:

$headers = "From: noreply@mydomain.com" . PHP_EOL;

Is this what you were thinking? And thank you for spotting this. 

For the first issue, I still don't understand what I'm exactly supposed to do. The code should be working, but not before I add preventDefault after submitting so the page doesn't refresh? Thank you once again.

Comment: I might know what the issue is.. I'm hosting this through Github pages, and those are static pages that don't support PHP. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Not with that host, no. Find a host which supports php. If you're desperate there are some free ones but the service is sometimes poor. Otherwise, expect to pay a few dollars a month for a reasonable experience,  a proper domain name and some techical support. Of course if you are only experimenting you can simply run the code on your own computer instead.